# Can we have a "non-linear estimator" of a linear parameter?

Tags: regression, least-squares

Given the linear regression model 
$$y=X\beta + \epsilon$$
Where $E(y|X)=X\beta$, and $Var(\epsilon)=\sigma^2I$.

The Gauss Markov Theorem states that the OLS estimator $b$ is the smallest variance unbiased **linear** estimator of $\beta$.

When I first read this, I used to read this "linear" as referring to the fact that $\beta$ is a linear parameter in the model. However, "linear" actually refers to the estimator $b$, not to the parameter itself.

And indeed in the proof of the Gauss Markov theorem given in "Greene, Econometric analysis (p. 60)", $b_{OLS}$ is contrasted with another "linear estimator" $b_0$, and the property that $b_0$ is linear is written as 
$$b_0=Cy$$

So this made me wonder, **what is the significance of the fact that OLS is a *"linear estimator"*, given that the model itself is already linear?**

- i.e. can we have non-linear estimators of linear parameters, and does this make sense?
- Are there non-linear estimators of $\beta$ (in the linear model given above), that are unbiased, and have smaller variance than $b_{OLS}$?
- Can we have linear estimators of non-linear parameters, and why would we do this (presumably they cannot be unbiased).

Comment: I believe [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/467783/247274) answers your first two questions.